# Reproducing a Restful url with variables in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, restful-url

Is there a way to reproduce a Restful url in Laravel 4 passing variables to it to test in browser simulating a GET?

When I do this:

```
http://172.17.0.2/vevey/pagseguro/notification/notificationCode=713B60-785F465F4619-DAA4BD3F89D4-1E090D
```

I get this:

[image: result]

When it should be only

```
'notificationCode' => string (56) "713B60-785F465F4619-DAA4BD3F89D4-1E090D"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a route like this :

```
Route::get('.../notification/notificationCode/{code}', ...)->where('code', '[a-fA-F0-9\-]');
```

and grab the `{code}` argument in your controller function ?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question. This is not a specific problem, For testing purpuses, I just need to know how to manually create an URL to reproduce something Laravel (or Ruby) does under the hoods to access a parametrised route. Tried many variations of it: http://puu.sh/42LC4.png. Thanks! :)